# toolbar all caps disable

Tags: android, android-actionbar, androidx

in my styles.xml

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="MainAppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <!--item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>-->
    <!--   theme UI controls like buttons, checkboxes and text fields, cursor or progress bar-->
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <!-- hide action bar -->
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

in Manifest.xml

in activity:

```
 mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolBar);
            setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

layout:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/tool_bar"/>

    <!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->
    <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

toolbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:background="#aabbcc"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="@dimen/tool_bar_height">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolBarConstraintLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolBar"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/tool_bar_height"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

        <ImageView android:layout_width="32dp"
                   android:id="@+id/imageView"
                   android:layout_height="32dp"
                   android:layout_marginLeft="48dp"
                   android:layout_marginStart="48dp"
                   android:src="@drawable/ic_app_logo"
                   app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                   app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                   app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        />

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/toolbaTitleTextView"
                style="@style/textViewOneLine"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:gravity="center|start"
                android:text="@string/application_name"
                app:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/toolBar"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/toolBar"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/toolBar" app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp" android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"/>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]
but in toolbar all chars are in upper case.
But I need only first letter in upper case.

Comment: what value does `application_name` have?

Comment: @OmidNejadabbasi "My app"

Comment: you have added app:textAllCaps="true" to Textview. remove that

Comment: @Rahul is right -> [TextView in android.developers.com](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:textAllCaps)